# Differential equation for $y = \ln(\cos(x+c_1)) + c_2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**My try:**
$$y' = \frac{-\sin(x-c_1)}{\cos(x-c_1)}\rightarrow y' = -\tan(x-c_1)$$
For removing $c_1$ value I did this by inversing the $\tan(x-c_1):$
$$x-c_1 = -\tan^{-1}(y')$$   $$\rightarrow c_1 = x+\tan^{-1}(y')$$ Hence $$y = \ln(\cos(2x+\tan^{-1}(y')))+c_2$$I **doubt** whether this way is correct or not because $y'$ is in a function!
If isn't correct , could anybody show the correct answer please ?

Comment: $u=\exp{y} =\exp{c_2} \cdot \cos(x+c_1)$. Equation for $u$ is $u''+u=0$, $u'=y' \exp{y}$, $u''=y'^2 \exp{y} + y'' \exp{y}$. Substituting in $u''+u=0$ gives $(y''+y'^2+1)\exp{y}=0 \Rightarrow y''+y'^2+1=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y''=-(\tan^2(x+c_1)+1)
=-(y')^2-1$

$y''+(y')^2+1=0$